# Отступы между колонками в адаптивной сетке

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Недавно читал про адаптивную сетку, вроде понятно всё, кроме одного. Как правильно добавлять отступы между блоками (точнее, колонками внутри row)? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Вот, тут я хотел сделать отступы, скажем, между content и sidebar. 
html:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#browserWidth {
  position: fixed;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234567;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.b-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: #c1c1c1;
}
.cols {
  background: #fd4;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.cols.col-1 {
  width: 8.333333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-2 {
  width: 16.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-3 {
  width: 25%
}
;
 .cols.col-4 {
  width: 33.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-6 {
  width: 50%
}
;
 .cols.col-7 {
  width: 58.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-8 {
  width: 66.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-9 {
  width: 75%
}
;
 .cols.col-10 {
  width: 83.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-11 {
  width: 91.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-12 {
  width: 100%
}
;
@media (max-width: 520px) {
  .cols.col-1,
  .cols.col-2,
  .cols.col-3,
  .cols.col-4,
  .cols.col-5,
  .cols.col-6,
  .cols.col-7,
  .cols.col-8,
  .cols.col-9,
  .cols.col-10,
  .cols.col-11,
  .cols.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before,
.row:after,
.row:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.b-header {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
  &_logo {
    color: #fd4;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
.b-sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
.b-content {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
}
.b-footer {
  height: 45px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <title>Grid And Others</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="b-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-12 b-header">
        <div class="b-header_logo">
          <a>LOGO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-3 b-sidebar">
        <a>.b-sidebar</a>
      </div>
      <div class="cols col-9 b-content">
        <a>.b-content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-12 b-footer">
        <a>.b-footer</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="browserWidth"></div>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("browserWidth").innerHTML = "width: " + window.innerWidth + "px";
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: приведите минимальный пример того о чем говорите

Comment: А добавлять простой `margin` пробовали? Ну или `padding`, если отступы нужны "изнутри".

Comment: @smellyshovel, пробовал (margin рушит верстку, padding не нужен)

Comment: @Андрей как они рушат верстку? Что происходит? margin и padding придуманы для создания отступов. Если у вас они "рушат верстку", значит вы что-то делаете неправильно. А придумывать костыли не советую, ибо это, скорее всего, нарушит семантику. Опишите поведение при *нормальном* добавлении отступов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**  `.cols.col-3 { width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; }` :

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#browserWidth {
  position: fixed;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234567;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.b-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.cols {
  background: #fd4;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;  
  text-align: center;
}
.cols.col-1 {
  width: 8.333333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-2 {
  width: 16.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-3 {
  width: 24%
}
;
 .cols.col-4 {
  width: 33.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-6 {
  width: 50%
}
;
 .cols.col-7 {
  width: 58.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-8 {
  width: 66.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-9 {
  width: 75%
}
;
 .cols.col-10 {
  width: 83.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-11 {
  width: 91.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-12 {
  width: 100%
}
;

.cols.col-3 {
  margin-right: 1%;
}

@media (max-width: 520px) {
  .cols.col-1,
  .cols.col-2,
  .cols.col-3,
  .cols.col-4,
  .cols.col-5,
  .cols.col-6,
  .cols.col-7,
  .cols.col-8,
  .cols.col-9,
  .cols.col-10,
  .cols.col-11,
  .cols.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before,
.row:after,
.row:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.b-header {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
  &_logo {
    color: #fd4;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
.b-sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
.b-content {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
}
.b-footer {
  height: 45px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <title>Grid And Others</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="b-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-12 b-header">
        <div class="b-header_logo">
          <a href="#">LOGO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-3 b-sidebar">
        <a href="#">.b-sidebar</a>
      </div>
      <div class="cols col-9 b-content">
        <a href="#">.b-content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-12 b-footer">
        <a href="#">.b-footer</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="browserWidth"></div>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("browserWidth").innerHTML = "width: " + window.innerWidth + "px";
</script>

</html>
```

**Вариант 2** просто `.cols.col-3 { padding-right: 1%; }`:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#browserWidth {
  position: fixed;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234567;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.b-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.cols {
  background: #fd4;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;  
  text-align: center;
}
.cols.col-1 {
  width: 8.333333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-2 {
  width: 16.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-3 {
  width: 25%
}
;
 .cols.col-4 {
  width: 33.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-6 {
  width: 50%
}
;
 .cols.col-7 {
  width: 58.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-8 {
  width: 66.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-9 {
  width: 75%
}
;
 .cols.col-10 {
  width: 83.33333333333333%
}
;
 .cols.col-11 {
  width: 91.66666666666667%
}
;
 .cols.col-12 {
  width: 100%
}
;

.cols.col-3 {
  padding-right: 1%;
}

@media (max-width: 520px) {
  .cols.col-1,
  .cols.col-2,
  .cols.col-3,
  .cols.col-4,
  .cols.col-5,
  .cols.col-6,
  .cols.col-7,
  .cols.col-8,
  .cols.col-9,
  .cols.col-10,
  .cols.col-11,
  .cols.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before,
.row:after,
.row:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.b-header {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
  &_logo {
    color: #fd4;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
.b-sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
.b-content {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
}
.b-footer {
  height: 45px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <title>Grid And Others</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="b-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-12 b-header">
        <div class="b-header_logo">
          <a href="#">LOGO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-3 b-sidebar">
        <a href="#">.b-sidebar</a>
      </div>
      <div class="cols col-9 b-content">
        <a href="#">.b-content</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols col-12 b-footer">
        <a href="#">.b-footer</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="browserWidth"></div>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("browserWidth").innerHTML = "width: " + window.innerWidth + "px";
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Создать свой CSS, подключить его после bootstrap.css и переопределить свойства нужного блока: изменить `padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;` на необходимые значения

Comment: Где в вопросе сказано, что речь идет о бутстрапе?

Comment: Класс .row подразумевает колонки бутстрапа, разве не так?

Comment: @Alex, нет, я не о bootstrap'e. Мне нужны были отступы между колонками (ну, блоками)..

Comment: @Alex абсолютно не так.

Comment: @Андрей в таком случае нажмите "Править" под вопросом и добавьте уже имеющийся код.

Comment: @smellyshovel, уже сделал